# Cannot run the Hello World Python application from Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP. Learning basics using Python.

I am able to run the Hello world application on App engine. Now I want to understand how to run the same Hello world application on an instance I created on the compute engine. I have done the following and not sure what wrong I am doing

Instance name: instance-1

Firewall rules:
[image]

Roles:
[image]

APIs and Services enabled:

[image]

**What's working**

1. On my Shell terminal I am inside my Hello World application folder and ran the commands

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user (install your app dependencies)`

`pip3 install gunicorn --user (Install the Gunicorn HTTP server)`

`~/.local/bin/gunicorn -b :8080 main:app (Run the Gunicorn HTTP server)`

and I am able to see my Hello World application running on the compute engine (Web preview - preview on port 8080): Success. I guess the application is running on the compute engine on 8080 and not on any instance

2. Through the console on VM instance I open the SSH terminal for my VM instance 'instance-1', I see the user@instance-1 on my terminal, install Apache2 and able to see the Apache2 Debian Default Page through the external ip: Success
3. on the SSH terminal for my VM instance 'instance-1' I run the command

    `jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &`

    and I see my Jupyter notebook running on GCP: Success (meaning instance is good, I can run a webapp on my instance)

Now I am assuming that I should be able to deploy my Hello world code on that specific instance through my SSH terminal (not through the Cloud Shell terminal).

So I first restart my VM so that the Jupyter notebook application no longer runs.

**What's not working**

 on my SSH terminal `user@instance-1:~$ cd default-service/`

1. i get inside my application folder, able to see all the 3 files. (app.yaml, main.py and requirement.txt)
2. ran the command to see if I am inside any project `gcloud compute project-info describe` and I could see my project
3. ran the command `gcloud app deploy` but it gives me an error message

    `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Unable to deploy to application [PROJECT-ID] with status [USER_DISABLED]: Deploying to stopped apps is not allowed.`
4. ran the command `~/.local/bin/gunicorn -b :8080 main:app` - it kept trying to sometime but failed saying `[ERROR] Can't connect to ('', 8080)`

I have went through lot of suggestions available based on which I have modified the roles, created firewall rules, enabled few of the APIs and Services.

Any help what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the status of your account? `with status [USER_DISABLED]`.

Comment: by account I guess you mean the project. When i run the command `gcloud compute project-info describe` on my SSH Terminal I see xpnProjectStatus: UNSPECIFIED_XPN_PROJECT_STATUS.

Comment: You have an error message `USER_DISABLED`. Check your billing account to see if your project is suspended.

Comment: I checked. It is not suspended. Just to double sure I enabled my app engine on the same project, ran the application and it worked. Also I am able to successfully access the Jupyter notebook on that compute engine instance

Comment: Die you try the command in the linux terminal or in the Jupyter terminal?

Comment: hi, I tried on the SSH terminal that opens from VM instance which I guess supports these Linux commands. (Opening Jupyter notebook on the instance was just an example that I was learning)

Comment: There are lots of example of how to run the Python hello world application on App Engine which I have learnt. Is there any source or link you can help me with where I can see how a Python application runs on an instance of a Compute Engine. I have an example for node.js but that's not what I am looking for.